# can't invoke an executable and plug to its output stream

Tags: racket

I want to invoke mvn command from within racket code, and then stay tuned to the process and get back the output of maven as it works, present it to the user line by line.

I have tried to implement it using a batch file that navigates to my maven project and invoke the mvn command (currently simple mvn clean will satisfy..)

```
cd\
cd projects\java\projA
mvn clean
```

I have tried to invoked this batch file using either system and process, but both returns me the same result: mvn is not recognized. (off course it is, as I can invoke this batch file on my own and it works perfectly).

```
(define invocation-method (lambda () (system "c:\\test.bat")))
;; capture output
(string-split (with-output-to-string invocation-method) "\n")
```

and the output:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'("\r" 
  "C:\\Users\\aviad>cd\\\r" 
  "\r" 
  "C:\\>cd projects\\java\\projA\r"
  "\r" 
  "C:\\projects\\java\\projA>mvn clean \r")
```

it seems that when I invoke it from racket context it is not familiar with the path variable or something (and perhaps even other environment variables ?).

any idea?

Comment: Try to execute the command `SET` this way. IIRC this should show all environment variables, PATH included.

Comment: Is there any difference if you use absolute paths?

Comment: By the time I Have tested the SET command, it was after restarting my machine (from different reasons), and then invoked the racket code and it worked well (the SET command revealed that the PATH variable includes my mvn, and the program worked well). I wonder why only restart made the PATH variable be updated in the eyes of the shell opened from racket...